# python file copy permission error

Tags: python, file-permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to copy a file from a location and save it with another name, 
but i am getting this error:

```
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/nginx-files/0000000007'
```

which quite obviously means that the script performing the operation has no permissions to do that.

Here are the user & group of script:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data 1504 Jun  3 16:27 main.py
```

user & group of file:

```
-rw-------  1 www-data www-data 40448 Jun  3 16:19 0000000007
```

user  & group of directory in which the file resides and is to be copied (currently the same directory)

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 www-data www-data  4096 Jun  3 16:56 nginx-files
```

These files are generated directly by `nginx`.

Comment: Doesn't matter permissions of script. What matters is user running it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thankyou it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The permissions depend on the user executing the file.

```
sudo -u www-data python main.py
```

might help by executing the `main.py` program as the `www-data` user.